# A bit of confusion regarding ComboBoxes, ValueMember and DisplayMember

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

This is on Windows Forms, .NET 4.0.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Lastname);
    }
}
```

I read on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx), that if no .DisplayMember is set to the comboBox control, it uses the default ToString of the object, that's the reason why I'm overriding the toString method.

The result is as expected:

[image]

Here's how I'm loading the data:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var people = LoadSamplePeople();
    comboBox1.DataSource = people;
}

private IEnumerable<Person> LoadSamplePeople()
{
    return new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "Sergio", Lastname = "Tapia" },
        new Person(){ Id = 2, Name = "Daniel", Lastname = "Tapia" }
    };
}
```

The problem arises, when I set the **.ValueMember** of the control, it seems display defaults to use **that** value.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var people = LoadSamplePeople();
    comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
    comboBox1.DataSource = people;
}

private IEnumerable<Person> LoadSamplePeople()
{
    return new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person(){ Id = 1, Name = "Sergio", Lastname = "Tapia" },
        new Person(){ Id = 2, Name = "Daniel", Lastname = "Tapia" }
    };
}
```

[image]

How would I set the valueMember but default the DisplayMember to the ToString method?

Please note that the display is a combination of two properties on the Person class. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just add an extra property:

```
public string DisplayName {
    get { return String.Format("{0} {1}", Name, Lastname); }
}

public override string ToString() { return DisplayName; }
```

and set the `.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";`

Comment: Yeah I thought about that. Probably be the best solution I guess, I was wondering if there was another way without having to create a separate property. :) Thanks! **EDIT:** In case anyone else reads, since we are assigning the DisplayMember we don't need to override the ToString method for it to display what we need.

Comment: Just had a case where the `DisplayMember` refused to show any public property, so had to use the `ToString` override, returning that property. Bizarre behaviour from `ComboBox` (was using `DataSource` etc).